# Get input value with jQuery and add it to form action before post it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have unknown many Forms and unknown many different values on my site. That is why I would send all necessary data over the action and use it with `$_GET['up']`.

I have an input field which I would send with my form too, whose value is given by the user.

How can I get this value with jQuery and add this to my action?

```
<form action="/de/site.html/index.php?up='.$sell['Name'].','.$sell['street'].',1,<script>$(\'.'.$a.'months1\').html(months)</script>" name="'.$a.'product_update1" method="get">
+ m: 
<input class="update_product" name="'.$a.'months1" value="1">
<button class="delete_product" name="'.$a.'update1" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
</form><br/>
<script>var months = $(\'.'.$a.'months1\').val();</scripts>
```

I tried already like above, but got errors like jQuery not defined. I'm very bad with jQuery.

Comment: Please post entire html contents of your file. Did you add jquery.js as a script on your html page?

Comment: also you are passing value in url means a query string so your form method should be get not post so please change it

Comment: Yes jquery.js is added on my page.

Comment: @ManthanDave oh you right thanks i changed it.

Comment: Your code gives me cancer. it is neither a phtml nor html. script tags open willy-nilly within a still opened tag? your whole code is wrong. please provide a better code.

Comment: @delato468 so you have stilll error after changing ? whats the error now you are facing ?

Comment: @ManthanDave Unexpected token < and still jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action ="your action url" id="form"  method="POST">
    <input class="update_product" name="'.$a.'months1" value="1">
    <button class="delete_product" name="'.$a.'update1" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

```
$("#form").submit( function(eventObj) {

var extra_fields1=$("#fielsid").val()
   $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
     .attr('name', "extra_fields1")
     .attr('value', extra_fields1)
    .appendTo('#form');

return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
Add perticuler id in form tag

```
<form action="somewhere" method="POST" id="form">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

$("#form").submit( function(eventObj) {
  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
      .attr('name', "something")
      .attr('value', "something")
      .appendTo('#form');
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Don´t understand how this code adds the var value of the input into my action tag.

Comment: in action tag is set you want to

Comment: get the extra fields and set it as hidden and submit

Comment: I think this won´t do what i like to, could you share an example how to apply with my code.